# Extension:Chrome.tabs.query does not work with 'url'

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension  to be click button on another page.
I do not know why the code does not work.
    The function does not click on the item 'ac_play'

**manifest**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "VkPlayer", // Название расширения
    "version": "1.0", // Номер версии
    "description": "Switching music in the VK with the keyboard", // Описание расширения
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "*://vk.com/audios*"
    ],
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"]
   },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "VKPlayer", // Название кнопки
    "default_icon": "1.png", // Иконка для кнопки
    "default_popup": "popup.html" // Всплывающее окно
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<style>body{
    background: #2f4d9a;
    width: 0;
    height:0;
}</style>
```

**index.js**

```
function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true},{'url':"http://vk.com/audio*"},function (tabs){
        console.log(tabs);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code : "document.getElementById('ac_play').onclick();"});
    })
}();
```

This code my website:

```
  <div id="ac_controls" class="fl_l">
    <div id="ac_play" class="fl_l"></div>
    <div class="next_prev fl_l">
      <div id="ac_prev" class="ctrl_wrap">
        <div class="prev ctrl"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="ac_next" class="ctrl_wrap">
        <div class="next ctrl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please **format your code properly**. There's a preview when you're editing a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  {'active': true}, {'url':"http://vk.com/audio*"},
  function (tabs){/*...*/}
)
```

is an invalid query. I have no idea what the logic is supposed to be, but..

1. If you wanted AND between those conditions, you need to make a query with them both: `{'active': true, 'url': "http://vk.com/audio*"}`
2. If you wanted OR between those conditions, you'll need to query for one and then filter manually for another.

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query(
     {'url':"http://vk.com/audio*"},
     function (tabs) {
       tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
         if(tab.active) {
           /* ... */
         }
       });
     }
   });
   ```

Most probably this is not the only problem with your code, but unfortunately you fail to explain in English what you need. [ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) may be more adapted for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer: I had to add the "tabs" permission to my manifest to make the "url" query work.